# Sharepoint 2013 On Prem Attachment loading issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, windows

I am facing issue while loading attachments from my intranet sharepoint site. While opening attachments it is keep on loading and says **sharepointserver took too long to respond** and unable to load the document. Can anyone provide me an insight about this issue. This is happening only while trying to open the attachment files.

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue occur in all file types in the site?

Did the issue only occur in one site or all sites in SharePoint farm?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache and re-open IE.
2. Create a new site, create a new list and attach a file to check if the same issue will occur.

3.Reboot the SharePoint server.

You could improve the SharePoint performance according to the article below.

[10 steps to optimize SharePoint performance.](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2210265/10-steps-to-optimize-sharepoint-performance.html)

[Top 3 Ways to Improve SharePoint Performance.](https://blog.enablingtechcorp.com/top-3-ways-to-improve-sharepoint-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to troubleshooting using ULSViewer for SharePoint logs. If yes, you can track the problem with ULS Logs. You can learn how to troubleshoot with ULSViewer from these addresses: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fesiro/2013/11/11/sharepoint-logging-and-troubleshooting-using-ulsviewer/ https://hasankoroglu.com/2015/12/29/sharepoint-hata-yakalama/